# How to call method from myScene.m in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

So I know that by using this code, I can pause my game when I go to the background and resume when I re-enter the game.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
 // pause sprite kit
 SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
 view.paused = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
 // resume sprite kit
 SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
 view.paused = NO;
}
```

With the code above, the game will resume automatically upon re-entering the app.
How do I call a method from `myScene.m` inside `applicationDidBecomeActive` to show a resume button and require it to be pressed before resuming the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSNotifications. They are one of the easiest and best methods to implement to send notifications between classes, such as a pause method.

In the AppDelegate, use the following methods to 'post' a notification to the notification center. This is not the end however, because the your GameScene class has to be 'observing/waiting' for these methods
to be called.
[image: appdelegate]

To add the observer, call this method in the `initWithSize` method in the GameScene class (or whatever class you want to call your methods in). [image: GameScene notification observer]

Now you added an Observer that calls the `handleNotification` method. If you haven't yet guessed it, you need to implement this method in your gameScene (or corresponding class). I would do something like this:

[image: handleNotification method]

The notification parameter is the name of the notification that gets called in the AppDelegate. You can place a different (or another) notification name in the app delegate such as `resumeGame`. Just remember that for every notification you post, you need to have an observer for that notification, and then a selector that gets called whenever the notification is observed. In your scenario, you might want to have a resume button pop up when the notification is handled. This way, you can call any selector/method you want from the delegate. Good luck!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
 // resume sprite kit
 SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
 view.paused = NO;
 MyScene *scene = (MyScene *)view.scene;
 [scene showResumeButton];
}
```